# How much in US dollars were designated for space exploration research grants in the US fiscal 2016?

Tags: research

In a breakdown of inter-program spending for research projects and federal grants, how much money did the US authorize for Space exploration in 2016?

Answers may include manned/unmanned missions, Maintenance/supply, training, IT/Communication, educational, etc.

Answer (score 3):

NASA asked for \$18.5 billion of the US budget for 2016, and NASA was granted \$19.3 billion. Here you can see how NASA planned to break down that budget:

[image: NASA FY 2016 Budget Request]

As Thomas W pointed out in the comments, a PDF version of the budget estimates is [also available](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/NASA_FY_2016_Budget_Estimates.pdf).

**Source**:

- [NASA Fiscal Year 2016 Budget Estimates](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/NASA_FY2016_Summary_Brief_corrected.pdf)
- [NASA's About to Have Its Biggest Budget in a Decade - The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2015/12/nasa-budget-2016-mars-rover-europa-mission-planetary-science/420912/)

Comment: for OP; if you want a Word version of the Budget Estimates: https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/NASA_FY_2016_Budget_Estimates.pdf

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that this $19.3 billion represented 0.5% of the Federal US budget for 2016 - that's half a penny for every dollar you spend in federal taxes. This is contrasted strongly by the [25% of the population](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2015/07/14/5-facts-about-americans-views-on-space-exploration/) who thinks that's too much money to spend on NASA!